# Admin module custom cms/page grid does not have any sort functionality

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

I have created an admin module that replicates the CMS->Page grid layout. I have copied the core code from `adminhtml\default\default\template\widget\grid.phtml` to my admin page template file and made my block for that template extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`.

The CMS pages display fine and I have also managed to add my own column to the grid, however none of the default columns (or my own) are sortable or filterable.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Have I made an error somewhere or would I manually need to make these default fields sortable?

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start would be this class, used for the product grid:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
```

In particular the functions

```
_prepareCollection()
```

and

```
_prepareColumns()
```

I've used that block as the basis for my own custom grids. If you need any further pointers feel free to let me know and I'll do my best to take a look

Comment: In addition, the enabling of sorting/filtering is usually done in the __construct() function.

Comment: @james Hey, thanks for this. I copied from app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Grid.php and sorting now works, however when I add/overwrite data for the rows with ---         
        foreach ($collection as $order) {
                $order->setData( 'title', 'some new title' ); 
} --- for example, the sorting then fails. Would you know why this might be or if I'm using the right method to change a rows data? thanks again.

Comment: In fact, even if I simply loop through my collection in the prepareCollection method and not do anything in that loop the sorting fails?

Comment: From what I can understand, sorting is done on the collection (i.e. database record). After `$order->setData(X, Y)`, are you saving (`$order->save();`)? If not, I don't think the collection will pick it up hence it appears not to work.